# Structure declaration in c with identifer

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am try to understand this C code:

```
typedef struct _IntElem *IntList;
typedef struct _IntElem { int head; IntList tail;} IntElem;
```

I understand that it defines a recursive type, a `list`. However I don't understand the way it is declared. What I understand is the second line, we define a structure named `IntElem` which consists of an integer and an `IntList`. But what is the `_IntElem` in this declaration?

The first line allocates memory for the list?

Comment: It's just a name to describe the struct, so could also call it using `struct _IntElem a;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The first line

  ```
   typedef struct _IntElem *IntList;
  ```

is to just create a `typedef` or an *alias* for `struct _IntElem *`. The alias is named `IntList`. FWIW, at this point of time, the definition of `struct _IntElem` need not to be known to the compiler.

- The second line

  ```
  typedef struct _IntElem { int head; IntList tail;} IntElem;
  ```

  1. Actually defines an user-defined type `_IntElem`, with two members, `head` as `int` and `tail` as `IntList`(`typedef`ed earlier)
  2. `typedef` the type to `IntElem`.

**Please Note:** There is actually no variable created, for either of the *type* (s) (*I'm not talking about the member variables, of course, they are part of the definition*). So, there is no memory allocated , as such.

So, to be explicit

> *But what is the `_IntElem` in this declaration?*

the `_IntElem` is the name of the user-defined data type. However, in some cases, it is optional. for example,

```
typedef struct { char name [32]; int age; float salary;} employee;
```

is both perfectly fine and legal, except the fact, in this case, we're creating an alias `employee` to an *unnamed* data type.

Answer (score 1):

In C, if we have:

```
struct X
{
     stuff....
};
```

then `X` is called a *struct tag*.  It means that `struct X` is the name of a type. `X` on its own is not the name of a type. In fact `X` on its own behaves like any other undeclared identifier; this struct definition only defines the specific usage `struct X`.

We might say that struct tags live in a different namespace to other identifiers (not to be confused with C++ namespaces!)

---

Sometimes people don't like typing `struct X` everywhere. So they use `typedef` (which, confusingly, means to create a type *alias*) in order to make a single identifier that names the type:

```
typedef struct X SX;
```

means that `SX` is a type. But since struct tags are in their own namespace, you could even write:

```
typedef struct X X;
```

which means that `X` on its own refers to the same type as `struct X` does.

---

Hopefully you understand the code you are looking at now. I think it would have been clearer to write:

```
struct IntElem
{
    int head;
    struct IntElem *tail;
};
```

with the optional addition to save typing:

```
typedef struct IntElem IntElem;
```

Pointer typedefs are evil, so `IntList` can be omitted entirely.  Possibly you could keep it around to use as an *opaque type* for the users of your list, but you should avoid using it during your list implementation.